# Separations of concerns and dependency management in automation project

Tags: c#, project-structure, automation

I'm working on an automation project in C# and it has 2 wrappers: `DesktopAutomation` and `BrowsersAutomation`. The first has a dependency on `UIAutomation.dll`s (access to the MS desktop elements) and the latter on Selenium. Their role is understood I hope ;)

Now, There are user actions on the browsers that require a dependency on `UIAutomation`(or `DesktopAutomation` for that matter), since Selenium gives you access to the DOM and not the extensions buttons in Chrome for example.

So my question is, what would be the correct way / best practice, software construction wise:

1. Adding a dependency to `BrowsersAutomation` on `DesktopAutomation` which has the advantage of a working project that has existing methods I can use.
2. Adding a direct dependency to `BrowsersAutomation` on `UIAutomation.dll`s which makes this project more generic. e.g. using it in other projects won't require another dependency.

Or, perhaps, some other configuration I haven't thought of...?

Comment: If the requirements change such that only the automation from within a browser remains, would it then be viable to drop `DesktopAutomation` completely without affecting the overall architecture and functionality? If yes, then `BrowserAutomation` does not have an actual dependency on `DesktopAutomation`. They just happen to share `UIAutomation.dll` as a common dependency.

Comment: `DesktopAutomation` is necessary regardless of `BrowsersAutomation`.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence of yours

> which has the advantage of a working project that has existing methods I can use

means there are reusable methods or classes which might be used both from `BrowsersAutomation` and from some non-generic parts of `DesktopAutomation`, right?

If that is correct, I recommend you refactor the reusable methods from `DesktopAutomation` to a place where they can be used from `BrowsersAutomation` and `DesktopAutomation` as well, for example, to a new DLL called `MyUIAutomation.DLL` (I assume you cannot put the methods into `UIAutomation.DLL` directly, because you have a 3rd party lib like Microsoft's `UIAutomationCore.DLL` in mind with that, right)?

This approach gives you the benefit you named in point 1 (reusage of existing methods) together with the advantage of not making `BrowsersAutomation` depend on the non-generic parts of `DesktopAutomation`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I like the idea of making another library which will be more generic. I'll give it a try.